# Multiple where in linq (xml)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I want to read link id of navlinks(l63) by giving linktext(Last 3 Months) and SecondaryLink linkid s14 in linq:

```
<SecondaryLink>
  <LinkID>
    <![CDATA[s14]]>
  </LinkID>
  <LinkText>
    <![CDATA[All Brands]]>
  </LinkText>
  <LeftMenu>
    <NavLinks>
      <LinkID>
        <![CDATA[l63]]>
      </LinkID>
      <LinkText>
        <![CDATA[Last 3 Months]]>
      </LinkText>
    </NavLinks>
  </LeftMenu>
</SecondaryLink>
```

This is what I have, I want to give one more where condtion in this.

```
 string secondaryid = doc.Descendants()
                         .Elements("LinkText")
                         .Where(x => x.Value == "Last 3 Months")
                         .Single()
                         .Parent
                         .Element("LinkID").Value;
```

that is linkid=s14

Comment: There is no question here.  Note the lack of a question mark?

Comment: hi want to read link id of navlinks(l63) by giving linktext(Last 3 Months) and SecondaryLink linkid s14 in linq

Comment: Adding a question mark as the first digit of your post does not turn it into a question.  [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on SO, and in general, [How to ask the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: It's not at all clear what the SecondaryLink element has to do with LeftMenu.

Comment: I edited this to the best of my ability, @Bruce Adams if you make additional suggested edits, I'll accept them. @ram - MOST of what I corrected were just typos, please put more effort into your future questions.

Comment: @Bruce This isn't his original question, it's been edited a few times and is slowly starting to resemble a question.  It's people like me harassing him to reformulate his post into a question that makes it answerable, as opposed to reading it, deciding it can't be answered, and moving on. ;-)

Comment: hi Bruce Adams can u pls help me :-(

Comment: @Bruce: If you think the question is obvious, could you explain where the SecondaryLink part comes in, given that they appear to be in fairly separate subtrees?

Comment: @Jon, I didn't say the actual question was obvious in regards to answering it or didn't mean that anyway. Just that it seemed obvious as to what he was trying to ask. Linq2XML is definitely not my strong point. But I had a crack at answering it. Have no idea if it's right or not?

Comment: @Bruce: The XML formatting isn't helping here... I'd misread it. Will edit, and then see if I can check your answer... Note that formatting the question sensibly is something that any questioner can do regardless of native language.

Answer (score 3):

```
    var q = from c in xml.Descendants("SecondaryLink")
            where (string)c.Element("LinkID") == "s14"
            where (string)c.Element("LeftMenu").Element("NavLinks").Element("LinkText") == "Last 3 Months"
            select c.Element("LeftMenu").Element("NavLinks").Element("LinkID");
```

Comment: Other than a cast to string for the result, that looks right to me.